# How to configure neo4j server to use bolt

Tags: configuration, neo4j

I am currently running awebapp with an embedded neo4j. Now I want to change to a standalone neo4j server using bolt. Neo4j has been loaded onto a standalone and port 7474 work as expected.

Using the following code works as expected:

```
var authority = neo4j.v1.auth.basic("neo4j", "XXXXXXXX");
_driver = neo4j.v1.driver("bolt://localhost ", authority, {encrypted:false});
```

However

```
        var authority = neo4j.v1.auth.basic("neo4j", "XXXXXXXX");
        _driver = neo4j.v1.driver("bolt://somesite.com/ ", authority, {encrypted:false});
```

Fails with:

```
neo4j-web.js:27568 WebSocket connection to 'ws://somesite.com:7687/' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
```

The port 7687 has been enabled. The neo4j version 3.0.4 and the server operating system is Centos 7.

What am I missing?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 6):

you need to enable remote connections by adding the following line to `conf/neo4j.conf`:

```
dbms.connector.bolt.address=0.0.0.0:7687
```

Comment: Thanks Stefan, A simple trap for beginners. I appreciate it.

Comment: Unrecognized seting. No declared setting with name: dbms.connector.bolt.address.

Answer (score 1):

Stefan's answer works for Neo4j 3.0 (see this [KB article](https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/explanation-of-error-websocket-connection-failure/)).

For those that are having an issue like Maulik, you are probably using a more recent version of Neo4j (3.5, 4.x), in which case you need to use the following instead:

```
dbms.connector.bolt.advertised_address=localhost:7687
dbms.connector.bolt.listen_address=0.0.0.0:7687
```